# change href-target by incrementing a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, href

I am working on a quiz, this quiz has a timer. When the timer ends it fires a scrollLeft animation that uses a href as target. What I am trying to do, to come around the problem that it always targets the first `.qAnswers li a` is to use a variable to change the name of the href-target.
Well, it doesn't seem to be working as planned, what am I doing wrong?

Here's a link to the project: http://www.carlpapworth.com/friday-quiz/#

HTML:

```
<div id="qWrap">
                <ul id="qBox">
<!--Q1-->           <li id="q1" class="qContainer">
                        <div class="qQuestion">Question I                       </div>
                        <ul class="qAnswers">
                            <li><a href="#q2" class="aWrong"><h3>Answer a</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#q2" class="aCorrect"><h3>Answer b</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#q2" class="aWrong"><h3>Answer c</h3></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
<!--Q2-->           <li id="q2" class="qContainer">
                        <div class="qQuestion">Question II                      </div>
                        <ul class="qAnswers">
                            <li><a href="#q3" class="aWrong"><h3>Answer 1</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#q3" class="aWrong"><h3>Answer 2</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#q3" class="aCorrect"><h3>Answer 3</h3></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
<!--Q3-->           <li id="q3" class="qContainer">
                        <div class="qQuestion">Question III                     </div>
                        <ul class="qAnswers">
                            <li><a href="#q4" class="aWrong"><h3>Answer 1</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#q4" class="aWrong"><h3>Answer 2</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#q4" class="aCorrect"><h3>Answer 3</h3></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//timer//

function timesUp(){
            $('#timerBar').animate({'width':'0px'}, 7000, function(){
                nextQuestion(function(){
                    resetTimer();
                }); 
            });                 
}

var hrefURL = '#q';
var hrefData = 2; <!-- VARIABLE -->
$('.qAnswers a:first').attr('href', hrefURL + hrefData);

function nextQuestion(event){
    var $anchor = $('.qAnswers a:first');
     $('#qWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).position().left
        }, 2000, function(){
            nextCount();  
hrefData++; <!-- INCREASE VARIABLE -->

        });

}
```

Comment: Im sorry, I feel like I might be able to help you solve this but I dont quiet understand what's wrong and what exactly your trying to accomplish. If the timer counts down, you want it to go back to the beginning?

Comment: Sorry, no, what I want is the animation to be fired. It works the first time (scrolling the `#qWrap` to the next li.qContainer with the id='#qN'), however the animation keeps firing at the `<li id='#q2'>`, since it always targets the first `.qAnswer a`. My way of coming around this was to make a variable for the #qN (N being the hrefData) and thus increasing the variable by one each time so it targets the next `<li id='#q2'>`.

Comment: If it's important that people don't cheat on this quiz (which I assume it is), I wouldn't use classes to indicate right and wrong answers, every modern browser can easily open the html source and see the easily named classes. Just a tip :)

Answer (score 1):

```
FINALY! I found the answer to my own problem: 
    var hrefURL = '#q';
    var hrefData = 2;
    $('.qAnswers a:first').attr('href', hrefURL + hrefData);

    function nextQuestion(event){
        var $anchor = $('.qAnswers a:first');
         $('#qWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).position().left
            }, 2000, function(){
                nextCount();  
    hrefData++;
    $('.qAnswers a:first').attr('href', hrefURL + hrefData); <!-- I need to fire this again for the hrefData++; to be applied  -->

            });

}
```